# How can I web scrape a paginated table while looping through URLs that hold different number of pages

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to find a way to loop through URLs and scrape paginated tables in each of them. The issue arises when some URLs have differing page numbers (in some cases there is no table!). Can someone explain to me where I went wrong and how to fix this? (Please let me know if you require further info.)

```
def get_injuries(pages):
    Injuries_list = []
    for page in range(1, pages+1):
        for player_id in range(1,10):
            headers = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"}
            url = 'https://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/neymar/verletzungen/spieler/' + str(player_id)
            print(url)
        
            html = requests.get(url, headers = headers)
            soup = bs(html.content)
            # Select first table
            if soup.select('.responsive-table > .grid-view > .items > tbody'):
                soup = soup.select('.responsive-table > .grid-view > .items > tbody')[0]
        
                try:
                    for cells in soup.find_all(True, {"class": re.compile("^(even|odd)$")}):
                        Season = cells.find_all('td')[1].text
                        Strain = cells.find_all('td')[2].text
                        Injury_From = cells.find_all('td')[3].text
                        Injury_To = cells.find_all('td')[4].text
                        Duration_days = cells.find_all('td')[5].text
                        Games_missed = cells.find_all('td')[6].text
                        Club_affected = cells.find_all('td')[6].img['alt']

                        player = {
                        'name': cells.find_all("h1", {"itemprop": "name"}),
                        'Season': Season,
                        'Strain': Strain,
                        'Injury_from': Injury_From,
                        'Injury_To': Injury_To,
                        'Duration (days)': Duration_days,
                        'Games_Missed': Games_missed,
                        'Club_Affected': Club_affected
                        }

                        players_list.append(player)
                except IndexError:
                    pass

            return Injuries_list
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
return Injuries_list
```

1. This should be in the outer most `for loop`. After looping once it's returning only one url.
2. Only one `for loop` is sufficient to get the data.
3. `players_list=[]` .I dont' see this, Create one at the start
4. you are not doing anything with this list `Injuries_list`. It's returning an empty list